# Monitor visual studio http request with fiddler

Tags: http, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am trying to monitor the following request from VS2012 on fiddler but can't:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8081/");
        var product = new Product() { Description = "blabla", CatalogName = "myName"};
        MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        // Use the JSON formatter to create the content of the request body.
        HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Product>(product, jsonFormatter);
        // Send the request.
        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.PostAsync(@"odata/Products/", content).Result;
        var result = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I've read about 2000 manual and feeds regards, but couldn't figure it out.
Any clue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By simply adding fiddler to the url

```
http://localhost.fiddler:8081/
```

Traffic is routed through fiddler and therefore being displayed on fiddler.

P.S.
As credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358261/805138

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link - http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic. Instead of localhost, use the machine name or the IPV4/6 adapter.

Comment: Thanks! But as mentioned I've ran into alllot of blogs and came out short on this specific method.
The weird thing is that using both http://ipv4.fiddler/ and http://127.0.0.1/
Does lead to "localhost" but when adding port number, such as: 
http://ipv4.fiddler:8081/ doesn't lead to same as http://localhost:8081
Really frustrating...

Comment: `ipv4.fiddler` is converted to `127.0.0.1`. `ipv6.fiddler` is converted to `[::1]`. `localhost.fiddler` is converted to `localhost`.