# Attach Fiddler Debugger to a WCF service hosted in IIS8

Tags: wcf, fiddler

I haven't been able to find any successful guidelines to capture data from a WCF service hosted in IIS through Fiddler.

I have a WCF service in production that is deployed in the following URL: http://localhost:88/MyService.svc

Obviously, if I open Fiddler on the server machine and wait until a user hits my service, nothing happens so at this point I am not sure how to capture the traffic here...

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the IIS web logs?

Comment: I looked into them but they are not very helpful...

Comment: Check this answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37773142/2581562)
Especially the web.config and code part.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any logging mechanism enabled for WCF service ?

Check whether service is in use.

If logging is happening at Service level and if it is not being reflected in your tool, then there would be some configuration issues.